# MailKit save Attachments

Tags: c#, .net, mailkit, mimekit

I'm try save attachments from message

```
foreach(MimeKit.MimeEntity at message.Attachments) 
{
    at.WriteTo("nameFile");
}
```

File saved, but when I open I get the error
   the file is corrupted or too large
The size of this file is 88 kb, but size of the file should be equal to 55 kb.

I think that in all recorded message file.

How do I only record the attachment?

MailKit v1.2.0.0 MimeKit 1.2.0.0

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You are saving the entire MIME object (including the headers). What you need to do is save the content.

```
foreach (var attachment in message.Attachments) {
    using (var stream = File.Create ("fileName")) {
        if (attachment is MessagePart) {
            var part = (MessagePart) attachment;

            part.Message.WriteTo (stream);
        } else {
            var part = (MimePart) attachment;

            part.Content.DecodeTo (stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: var part = (MimeKit.MessagePart)attachment;
here I get an exception "Failed to bring the object type MimeKit.MimePart type MimeKit.MessagePart

Comment: part.ContentObject.DecodeTo(stream);
and here i get error: "MimeKit.MessageParts" does not contain a definition for "Content_Object". Unable to find a method of expansion "ContentObject", receiving a first argument of type "MimeKit.MessagePart" (missing using directive or an assembly reference?)
can be a problem in versions?

Comment: what is your version MimeKit and MailKit?

Comment: You did not copy my code correctly if you got those exceptions because MessagePart does not have a ContentObject property, only MimePart does.

Comment: Each `MimeEntity` in the `message.Attachments` enumeration can be either a `MimePart` or a `MessagePart`. `MessagePart` items have a `.Message` property that represents the content while `MimePart` objects have a `ContentObject` that represent the content.

Comment: @jstedfast I noticed that not all attachments are always listed in the message.Attachments (like inline pdf files) . Can we be sure that all pdf/image attachments are processed when using message.BodyParts that have a MimePart.FileName ?

Comment: Hi there @jstedfast ! Seems that ContentObject is actually deprecated. I'm trying to get the attachment's data as a `byte[]` but `part.Content.Stream.CopyTo(memoryStream)` is actually saving the whole MIME entity. Any handful way to go? Thanks.

Comment: `part.Content.DecodeTo(memoryStream)` is what you want. `part.Content.Stream.CopyTo()` will copy the base64 encoded content to the memory stream which is probably what you are mistaking for "the whole MIME entity".