# How to download multiple attachments per message with MailKit?

Tags: c#, mailkit, mimekit

I've looked at a lot of the other questions on stackoverflow about this, but I'm still confused.

I want to download the attachments of emails- I was successfully able to do this, but only if the email had ONE attachment; when an email has more than one attachment, it stops working.

**How do I download multiple attachments per email?**

Also, is there a way to determine the file extension when downloading? Currently, for example, if there is a pdf attachment, the file downloads, but with no .pdf, so windows doesn't know the file type.

The code below is from here: [MailKit save Attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227622/mailkit-save-attachments). I've been basing my code off of that.

```
foreach (var attachment in message.Attachments)
{
    using (var stream = File.Create ("fileName"))
    {
        if (attachment is MessagePart)
        {
            var part = (MessagePart) attachment;
            part.Message.WriteTo (stream);
        }
        else
        {
            var part = (MimePart) attachment;
            part.ContentObject.DecodeTo (stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you pasted will already save all attachments.

Look at the raw message source. Does each "attachment" that you consider to be an attachment have a header `Content-Disposition: attachment`? If not, that's the problem you are hitting.

You can instead use `message.BodyParts` and apply your own logic to determine if the part is what you would consider to be an "attachment".

> Also, is there a way to determine the file extension when downloading? Currently, for example, if there is a pdf attachment, the file downloads, but with no .pdf, so windows doesn't know the file type.

Yes. You can check the file extension on the `FileName` property on `MimePart` objects.

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was- thank you! It wasn't recognizing the attachment as an "attachment" (so there was no `Content-Disposition: attachment` heaer), because it came in through the email body, so `message.BodyParts` is exactly what I needed. Thanks for the help.